# matplotlib pdf savefig exiting early

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've copied the example given [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) and when I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Project work\pdf.py", line 9, in <module>
    with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

So where do I go from here?
Thanks

Comment: I get the same error with matplotlib 1.2.1, maybe it's doc for 1.3.1 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PdfPages` has become a context manager only in version 1.3.1. See the [chagelog](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2013-October/010071.html).

In particular, observe the following line:

> Added a context manager for creating multi-page pdfs (see `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages`).

Comment: Ok, just checked. Apparently I downgraded a while back for some reason. My fault. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I had to do this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
```

And also avoid using `plt.figure()` which invokes the display.